# Destructor of an n-ary tree struct

Tags: c++, memory, struct, memory-leaks

I have the following code:

```
const int MAXCHILD = 10;

struct Node {
    Node *child[10];

    Node();
    void deleteNode(Node *n);
    ~Node();
};

Node::Node() {
    for(int i=0; i<MAXCHILD; i++) {
        child[i] = NULL;
    }
}

void Node::deleteNode(Node *n) {
    if(n == NULL) {
        return;
    } else {
        for(int i=0; i<MAXCHILD; i++) {
            deleteNode(n->child[i]);
        }

        for(int i=0; i<MAXCHILD; i++) {
            n->child[i] = NULL;
        }
    }

    n = NULL;
}

Node::~Node() {
    Node *n = this;
    deleteNode(n);
}

int main() {
    Node *n = new Node();

    ...

    delete n;
    n = NULL;

    return 0;
}
```

This is what I've tried.
I don't get any critical errors while compiling/testing but when I test for memory leaks with Valgrind, it shows I'm constantly making memory leaks.

I'm aware there are many flaws in my destructor; what would be the problem?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: You are missing to `delete n;` in your `deleteNode()` function (shouldn't be done for `this`).

Comment: Store your children in `unique_ptr`s.  Oh, and call `delete` to return memory you are done with.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Would `delete n;` come after `t = NULL;` or before that?

Comment: @Yakk Sorry, what are `unique_ptr`s? I'm not familiar with them.

Comment: @Haxify Look [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm currently working on an assignment in university and I think we're not allowed to use things we're not taught yet, so I think I can't use `unique_ptr`s. Also, I heard the server we're working on does not support C++11.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I figured `delete n;` comes before `t = NULL;` though, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The memory leak is caused by your never deallocating the children.
(Setting the pointers to `NULL` isn't enough.)

Your destructor could be as simple as this:

```
Node::~Node() {
    for(int i=0; i<MAXCHILD; i++) {
        delete child[i];
        child[i] = nullptr;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm still getting memory leak; I guess it's a problem from some other parts of the program then. Thank you anyway, for the simple destructor! I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

The other reason of memory leak also can be recursive generation or construction of children nodes. It will be better if you change child data field inside structure and manage it in a different way like carrying it somehow inside of the constructor or linking childs and parent externally. Try it may be it will get you out of memory leak